# Is there a Google Sheets function for 2 or more repeating text in a row, based on text from another cell?

Tags: google-sheets

Bassically, Lets say we have Row A, B and C
Row A is name; Row B is a ID, Row C is another ID. I have a function where if Row B repeats twice, the cell becomes red.
Lets take some examples:

```
Lets say in A1 we have "Joe"
In B1 we have his ID - 1234
In C1 we have his 2nd ID - 7a1d
```

```
In A2 we have "Jack"
In B2 we have his ID - 9876
In C2 we have his 2nd ID - 7a1d
```

**Because B1 and B2 are different, but C1 and C2 are the same, both cells are RED**

Now lets say we John changed his name to Thomas, so we will have:

```
A1 - "Joe"
B1 - 1234
C1 - 7a1d
```

```
A2 - "Thomas"
B2 - 1234
B2 - 7a1d
```

**Because in this case, B1 and B2 are the same, C1 and C2 will show BLUE, to indicate that he changed his name**

I achieved the first part, I just need help with the 2nd one. I need to formula to be in Conditional Formatting.

Comment: This isn't very clear. `Row A`? Also, use a [mark down table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) for sample data.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fzMXF9XFtNs2wJLOwi4VmKB3RmZSq3j_echoTHYcqKo/edit?usp=sharing 
Check this sheet please, its a example of what im trying to make, but hopefully more clear to understand

Comment: Sorry, not that clear. I can see you're trying to match some duplicate ID's for different names, but give some examples of like 10 rows with the desired output. And please clean up the question to have precise and accurate language.  There is no `Row A, B, and C` in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
=AND(B1=B2,C1=C2)
```

You can anchor columns or rows if you need to do it extensive to other rangea